# setting up two git accounts on one machine based on parent folder

Tags: git, github, jira

For work my company uses an atlassian suite.  For personal projects I use github.  What I would like to be able to do is have my personal git account associated with home/personal and my work git associated with home/work but I don't see any good way to do this.  I have seen suggestions for using ssh with two github accounts online which won't work in my situation (I believe).

If this isn't possible what do most people do in this situation?  Currently my `git config --global` settings are associated with my work information.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Git stores configuration options in three separate files, which lets
>   you scope options to individual repositories, users, or the entire
>   system:
>
> - `<repo>/.git/config` – Repository-specific settings .
> - `~/.gitconfig` –  User-specific settings. This is where options set with the `--global` flag are stored.
> - `$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig` – System-wide settings.
>
> ref: https://es.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-config

---

> ```
> usage: git config [options]
>
> Config file location
>     --global              use global config file
>     --system              use system config file
>     --local               use repository config file
> ```

So you should use either 2 different os users or configure each repo separately

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'll try it out tomorrow before I mark it is the answer.

Comment: Yes it did - although I have no system config file but it doesn't seem to matter. Thanks again.